# Что значит выполнить TODO?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

Есть задача: написать тест ExampleTest(junit) и выполнить TODO. Что значит выполнить TODO?

```
package com.example.cinema.base.webapp.facade.admin.impl;

import com.example.cinema.base.models.dto.ProductionStudioRequestDto;
import com.example.cinema.base.models.entitys.ProductionStudio;
import com.example.cinema.base.converter.ProductionStudioMapper;
import com.example.cinema.base.service.entity.impl.ProductionStudioServiceImpl;
import com.example.cinema.base.webapp.facade.admin.ProductionStudioServiceFacade;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductionStudioServiceFacadeImpl implements ProductionStudioServiceFacade {

    private final ProductionStudioServiceImpl productionStudioService;
    private final ProductionStudioMapper productionStudioMapper;

    @Override
    public void save(ProductionStudioRequestDto dto) {
        ProductionStudio studio = productionStudioMapper.toEntity(dto);
        productionStudioService.save(studio);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(long id) {
        //TODО валидация на существование
        productionStudioService.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(long id, ProductionStudioRequestDto dto) {
        //TODО валидация на существование
        ProductionStudio studio = productionStudioMapper.toEntity(dto);
        productionStudioService.save(studio);
    }
}
```

Контроллер

```
package com.example.cinema.base.webapp.rest.admin;

import com.example.cinema.base.models.dto.ProductionStudioRequestDto;
import com.example.cinema.base.webapp.facade.admin.ProductionStudioServiceFacade;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/admin")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AdminProductionStudioRestController {

    private final ProductionStudioServiceFacade productionStudioServiceFacade;

    @PostMapping("/studios")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> addProductionStudio(@RequestBody ProductionStudioRequestDto dto) {
        productionStudioServiceFacade.save(dto);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/studios/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteProductionStudio(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        productionStudioServiceFacade.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping("/studios/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> updateProductionStudio(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
                                                             @RequestBody ProductionStudioRequestDto dto) {
        productionStudioServiceFacade.update(id, dto);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: "TODO" -> "to do" -> "то что должно быть сделано". Словом "TODO" обозначают место в коде где нужно сделать изменения. Всегда сопровождается пояснением: "// TODO: enter your code here",  "// TODO: speed up search". Когда изменения сделаны, TODO убирается.

Comment: По тесту как сделать TODO?

Comment: По тесту _чего_?  В экстремальном программировании есть подход TDD (Test Driven Design) -- там тесты пишутся _до разработки кода_.  У вас должен быть какой-то код, который вы должны протестировать.  Это и будет ваша реализация TODO.

Comment: Вставьте в вопрос пример кода.

Comment: Как сделать тест на метод save? Как в контроллере?

Comment: В тесте после save нужно проверить, что объект действительно создан (в идеале - с теми же данными, что указаны при его создании), при update - что действительно обновлен, при delete - что после удаления он уже не существует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде стоит комментарий

```
//TODО валидация на существование
```

Стоит он в методах для удаления и изменения записи. Видимо предполагается, что в эти методы надо добавить код для проверки существования записи.

Т.е., к примеру, перед тем как удалить запись по **id**, надо сначала проверить, что такая запись существует.

Так как это, судя по всему, тестовое задание, то делать надо "красиво". Вероятней всего от вас ожидают, что проверку вы реализуете как отдельный метод. А так же корректно сделаете информирование об ошибках. В тех случаях когда записи не существует.

Answer (score 0):

Там в коде два раза есть `//TODО валидация на существование`. Именно это вам и нужно сделать - провести валидацию на существование после выполнения тех двух функций.

Comment: В save что сделать? Просто записать в базу и удалить?

Comment: @svil, записать в базу, и проверить что записалось (и записалось то что записывали). Я вам в комментарии к вопросу написал.